# What Soboblev embedding i could use in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to understand why this inequality is true

$$ \Vert f\Vert_{L^2}^{p}\cdot h\left(\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}\right) \leq c \Vert f\Vert_{k+1}^{p} \cdot h\left(\Vert f\Vert_{k+1}\right), $$

where $ \Vert \cdot\Vert_{k+1} $ denotes the usual norm of the Sobolev Space $ H^{k+1}(R^n) $, $ h(y) $ denotes a nondecreasing nonnegative and continuous function, c is a costant, $k \geq 0 $ and $ p> 1$.

Maybe i can use an embedding theorem? which one? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Looks like a key comparison needed here is between $||f||_{\infty}$ and $||f||_{k+1}$.  This should allow a comparison between $h ( ||f||_{\infty}) $ and (a constant times) $h ($||f||_{k+1})$.  Although I am not sure why $h$ needs to be continuous.

Cursorily (haven't checked the details), a candidate embedding theorem is [Rellich-Kondrashov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich–Kondrachov_theorem).

Comment: This can only be correct if $k+1 > n/2$ since otherwise $H^{k+1}$ cannot be embedded into $L^\infty$. Even then it can only be true if $h$ has polynomial growth, since otherwise there are scaling problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a bit of Fourier analysis, one can show that, for $s>\frac{d}{2}$,
$$H^s(\mathbb{R}^d) \hookrightarrow L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d).$$
In particular, consider
$$\|f\|_{L^\infty} \leq \|\hat{f}\|_{L^1} \leq \|\langle \xi\rangle ^{-s}\|_{L^2} \|\langle \xi\rangle ^{s}\hat{f}\|_{L^2} \lesssim \|f\|_{H^s},
$$
where the first inequality follows, pretty much directly, from the Fourier inversion formula.

Now, $\|f\|_{L^2} \leq\|f\|_{H^{k+1}}$ for every $k\geq 0$, so that part is fine, too. But, you still have some work to do. In particular, you have
$$h(\|f\|_{L^\infty}) \leq h(c\|f\|_{H^s}),$$
but you need to get to
$$h(\|f\|_{L^\infty}) \lesssim h(\|f\|_{H^s}).$$
You may need some additional assumptions on $h$ (particularly on how $h$ scales) to do this.

As a bit of a tangent, it's actually the case that for $s > \frac{d}{2} + k$, we have $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d) \hookrightarrow C^k(\mathbb{R}^d) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$.